# Flash Datagrid change cell color depending upon updated data

Tags: flash, datagrid, cellrenderer, labelfunction

I have a datagrid in my Flash app whose data keeps updating quite frequently.
On every update, I need to change the cell color of only those cells whose data has changed.
That too, if the updated value is less than the older value then the cell color should change to RED else, GREEN.

I have tried using labelFunction, cellrenderer, etc. But to no avail.
By no means, I am able to access the present data in the cells to compare it with the new data.

This has drawn me to my wits end.
Last few hair left to be pulled out from my head!

Thanks in Advance for any help!

Comment: a kind of example code might help me understand the problem

Answer (score 1):

Thats what you need: http://blogs.adobe.com/pdehaan/2007/06/setting_a_flash_data_grids_bac_1.html

get the fla example: http://blogs.adobe.com/pdehaan/code/section13.example1.zip

Comment: Hi nelsond8, thanks for your reply. But, the example that you sited already contains the color to render the cell with in the data itself.

In my case though, what I need is to identify the cell color based on the difference between the present cell data & the new data to be shown in that cell.

Comment: where is your data coming from? a database or xml? I used that class for something similar to your problem, in my case every time I added a a row of different type the bg color would change. Do you have a live example? I quite positive you can achieve of you want using the code I gave you!

Comment: Hi nelsond8, thanks for the code. But, what I was looking for is a way to compare the current & new cell value for each cell of a datagrid column. I was hoping this could be achieved by using either cellrenderer or labelFunction. But, turns out you cannot access the data currently in the cell in both labelFunction as well as CellRenderer methods. So, finally I opted to comparing the new dataset with the dataprovider of the datagrid & inserting a few extra parameters. Now with the help of the code you mentioned & these extra parameters that I added, I am able to update cell bgcolor in my grid.